# accessing multiple matlab gui figures for plotting

Tags: matlab

I have multiple figures inside a MATLAB GUI and I want to plot on both of them in turns inside a for loop, how can I "pick" which of the figures will be used by the plotting functions?
i.e. how to specify exactly which figure will be used by the plotting function when I call it?

Comment: Can you post the code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your GUI handles are in "handles", then all you need to do is access the figure's axes

```
axes(handles.axes1);
```

plot ...

```
axes(handles.axes2);
```

plot ...

Where axes1 and axes2 refer to your figures' tags

Comment: it's even simpler to pick the axes in the call to `plot`: `plot(axes name,...)`

Comment: but this way is more generic as it would work irrespective of the capabilities (overloaded) of the plotting functions

Comment: `axes` also brings the axes into focus and makes it the `CurrentAxes`, which may or may not be desirable behavior. Explicitly specifying the parent axes with the `plot` command does not do this.